# How to filter currency without changing position of the symbol

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am having this problem:

```
{{100 | currency:'‎€'}}
```

the output is fine **100 ‎€**, but when i change the language for example en-US culture, the symbol changes its position so it becomes **‎€ 100**.

What i want is that symbol stays on its position even language is changed. 
i can do like:

```
{{100 | currency:'‎'}} {{'‎€'}}
```

but in that case if i have $ as currency, it will be **100$ not $100.**

So i don't want hard coded stuff, i would like to have dynamic filter that will set place of its symbol in one place.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your **custom filter** like

```
app.filter('customCurrency', function () {
return function (value) {

    // Do your logic here and append your currency
    // symbol before or after of your value as per your requirement

    return value
}; });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own filter or directive, but I think the better approach would be to set the locale on Angular using l10n.

[i18n and l10n](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n)

And if you need to force a change of localization from europe to en-Us you can do it programmatically, this make sense because you need to convert EUR to USD$.